# Automating ssh-add private keys with a common password

Tags: bash, ssh, automation

I have searched but the solutions I found were only focused on using a single key file.
Suppose I have a set of private keys which require the same password (and that I am confortable with such a setup from a security perspective).

How could I go about making a `bash` script that reads a password from `stdin` and invokes `ssh-add` for each of the private keys using the same password?

I do not have `-p` available for `ssh-add`.

I am trying to avoid writing the password to a file (even if temporary).
I came with this so far but I am unsure how to go or if this is possible:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $(ps ax | grep [s]sh-agent | wc -l) -gt 0 ] ; then
    printf "> 'ssh-agent' is running.\n"
else
    printf "> 'ssh-agent' needs to be running. Exiting.\n"
    exit 0
fi

unset password
prompt="> Please input your password: "
while IFS= read -p "$prompt" -r -s -n 1 char
do
    if [[ $char == $'\0' ]]
    then
         break
    fi
    prompt='*'
    password+="$char"
done

printf "\n> Adding key files...\n"

## declare an array variable
declare -a arr=("key-1.ppk" "key-2.ppk" "key-3.ppk")

## now loop through the above array
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
   #echo "$i"
   ssh-add "$i" < <(echo "$password")   

done
```

Also tried the following to pass into `stdin`:

```
echo $password | ssh-add "$i"
```

I also thought about using this in the loop:

```
{
/usr/bin/expect << EOF
  spawn ssh-add $HOME/.ssh/$i
  send "$password\r"
  expect eof
EOF
}
```

But then it would ask me to input a password for each individual key, defeating the purpose of automation.
Unless there is a way for a single `spawn ssh-add` to receive one single password via `expect` (only one prompt) and add more than one key with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have same password for all the keys then you can pass multiple keys to `ssh-add` and it prompts for password only once and adds all those keys to the ssh-agent.

eg:

```sh
$> arr=("id_ecdsa" "new_test_key")
$> ssh-add ${arr[@]}
Enter passphrase for id_ecdsa:
Identity added: id_ecdsa (test_user@host_test)
Identity added: new_test_key (test_user@host_test)

$> ssh-add -l
256 SHA256:urYhdMK9UZyLl+p8cC7ehdImYfvsmtJFtQmESWoczmM test_user@host_test (ECDSA)
256 SHA256:53obuQkRzLGW5iUJdmFPNvSK1quUSlCi4gbQkKsJinY test_user@host_test (ECDSA)
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. The ability of `ssh-add` to receive them as an array like this simplifies things.

Answer (score 1):

Password can be passed via environment variable :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
  
read password

ssh_askpass=$HOME/.ssh_askpass

echo 'echo "$password"' > $ssh_askpass; chmod 700 $ssh_askpass

ppk=key-1.ppk
export password
SSH_ASKPASS="$ssh_askpass" ssh-add $ppk < /dev/null

rm -f "$ssh_askpass"
```

Comment: While this one is useful, it does have the inconvenience of writing to disk (granted, I didn't specify that restriction in my question). Up-voting your answer though, as it is useful.

Comment: @Blitzkoder, Updated, now the password is passed by enviroenment variable.